# node Socket.io links how will give in server not localhost(wamp/xampp)

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to socket session but I learned how it will works in wamp/xampp localhost.
But when I move to server that is hosting. it will not work.

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Above this work in wamp/xampp. but not found in hosting server.
What should I give on src.
My hosting is be like:
aaa.bbb.com and its port is 8803 or
bbb.com and its port is 8803.

I have tried the ways are to be include as like

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://aaa.bbb.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://bbb.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

My server side code is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var async = require('async');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
   host     : 'XXXXX',
   user     : 'XXXXX',
   password : 'XXXX',
   database:'XXXXX',
 });

 var chatserver=require('./chatserver.js');
 var chatpage=io.of('/as/chatRoom').authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
 console.dir(handshakeData);
 handshakeData.page = '/welcome/chatRoom';
 callback(null, true);
 }).on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.dir(socket.handshake.page);
   chatserver.getUserFeeds(chatpage,socket,io,pool,async);
});
```

Comment: What happens when you try entering socket.io? Doss it load infinitely or do you get some error? Also, do you use nginx or apache, or maybe something else?

Comment: whenever i use above script line, socket.io.js is not found i got error

Comment: Could you show us your server code as well?

Comment: I have edit question with server side js

Comment: I got console error Unexpected token < in socket.io.js

Comment: Did you try vising your address `http://bbb.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` and checking what's in there? Is there `socket.io.js` code? It looks like your server did not serve this file.

Comment: yes that time i got the console error of http://bbb.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js not found

Comment: Try `io.serveClient(true)` after `var io = socket.listen(server)`. It is true by default, but who knows. Maybe it will work

Comment: Its also not worked

Answer (score 4):

On the server side of index.js of node you will need to require io, on http server

```
var 
app = require('express')(),
http = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(http);`
```

I am unsing handlebars as my templating system so, o i go on that. On your home template file you will add

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://bbb.com:3000');
   socket.on('connect', function(){
       socket.emit('authenticate', {data: "token"});
       socket.on('error', function(err){ alert(err); 
   });
   socket.on('unauthorized', function(err){
       alert("Disconnected");
       console.log("There was an error with the authentication:", err.message);
    });
    socket.on('disconnected', function() { alert('Disconnected') });
 });
 </script>
```

That works for me on live server.

Comment: Socketio spawns its own http server when you do not provide one. I'm not sure if this will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

With your code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

The socket.io.js path is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

You need to use javascript or php.

## Javascript :

(Dynamic js include)

```
var PORT = 3000;
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://" + document.location.hostname + ":" + PORT + "/socket.io/socket.io.js";
script.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Socket.io: unfound.");
};
script.onload = function () {
    console.log("Socket.io: loaded.");
    // Your code here.
    // startSocketIO();
};

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
// <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

## PHP :

```
<script src="http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answering. It work with my code itself. Only think we have to allow the PORT 3000 in server. Add port number to IP tables or disable server firewall and then it works fine :)